# Rails form submit operate like a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So ultimately what I'm trying to do is get the form to be split across two different columns with the status to be in one column and the save button in another column next to the link_to OR have the form's submit operate like a link_to. The form automatically applies some CSS that's causing the issue of splitting the form.

```
  <tbody>
    <% @training_resource.spud_users.each do |training| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= training.full_name %></td>
        <% utr = training.user_training_resources.where(training_resource: @training_resource).first %>
        <td class="utr-form">
         <%= tb_form_for [:admin, utr], url: admin_update_utr_path(utr), :remote => true, :html => {:id=>'form_id'}, :data => {:errors => :inline, :success => admin_training_resources_path} do |f| %>
           <%= f.select :status, UserTrainingResource.statuses.map {|k,v| [k.humanize, k]}, selected: utr.status %>

       </td>
        <td class="table-actions">
           <%= f.tb_save_buttons('', admin_update_utr_path(utr)) %>
         <% end %>
           <%= link_to 'submit', admin_update_utr_path(utr), :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()" %>
           <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_destroy_utr_path(utr), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'  %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to change the form save button to be a link_to. Right now I have it here under link_to 'submit'. It however does not operate like the tb_save_button as it doesn't redirect to the correct location or save.

Comment: Please do not query the database in your view! The `utr` lookup belongs in your controller! Also, you can redirect in the create action, as @abax suggested.

Comment: Honestly the query is really screwing up as whatever is being "updated" will actually be overwritten to a different user.

Comment: If you add your console output when you submit your form to your original queation, we will be able to help you out with that (also, your updated controller and view code). Or, because this question is a bit old, just ask a new question with your updated code and question (because the redirect seems like it is not your main problem).

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in the controller.

```
(example)
def create
  if utr.save
    redirect_to admin_update_utr_path(utr)
  else
    # render new form or display the previous view
  end
end
```